# Difference in ASP.NET file uploading functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am learning how to upload a file to a server in C# ASP.NET.

What is the difference between these 2 functions:

- `element.PostedFile.SaveAs();`
- WebClient's `wc.UploadFile();`

Answer (score 2):

They are *extremely* different.

`HttpPostedFile` represents a file that has been sent to your server from a client.

`WebClient.UploadFile()` allows you to send a file to an arbitrary server from your client.

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient`'s `UploadFile` makes an HTTP POST. `WebClient` is like a web browser.

Whereas, `PostedFile` is the property of the control that represents the POSTed file.